# how to clear flash messages in authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

Hi I have included given code in my controller

```
def create
    @user_session = User.new(user_params)
    if @user_session.save
      redirect_to apps_path
    else
      render send_notice("ERROR", find_error(@user_session), :new)
    end
end
```

in my en.yml file

```
authlogic:
    error_messages:      
      password_invalid: Password is not valid
```

so when I give correct username and wrong password then it gives me error message ***Password is not valid*** but when I give correct details after that it gives me same error of ***Password is not valid*** after login.
Please guide me how to solve this I don't have to give any success message

Comment: Use `@user_session.save!` and check what validations are failing. You can do `Rails.logger.info @user_session.errors.full_messages`

Comment: I have solved this just by giving flash[:notice] = '' in my if condition

Comment: Then add it as a answer and accept it, so that it's helpful for others